# how to add more arguments to add_p() tests in gtsummary

Tags: r, p-value, chi-squared, gtsummary

while applying add_P(), I get errors for some variables. so I manually specify the test type for those variables. Now I do not get error anymore. but I get warnings that " Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect". 
I am going to try the suggestion in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81483/warning-in-r-chi-squared-approximation-may-be-incorrect. 
I just do not know how to add chisq.test(a, **simulate.p.value = TRUE**)
any suggestions?

```
gtobject %>%
                  gtsummary::add_p(
                      test = c(var1,
                               var1) ~ "chisq.test.no.correct"
                      )
```

Comment: According to the documentation, you could create a custom function and pass it i.e. `chisq.test_new <- function(data, variable, by, ...) {
  data <- data[c(variable, by)] %>% dplyr::filter(complete.cases(.));
  chisq.test(x = data[[variable]], y = as.factor(data[[by]]), correct = FALSE, simulate.p.value = TRUE) %>% 
     broom::tidy()
}` and then use; `gtobject %>%  gtsummary::add_p(
                      test = c(var1,
                               var1) ~ "chisq.test_new"
                      )`  (not tested)

Comment: The link is [here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/gtsummary/html/tests.html)

Comment: Use the `add_p(test.args=)` argument to pass additional arguments